# AWS Cognito timeout redirects to Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are using Cognito with an external provider and are having an issue with the session timing out if the user takes too long to login on the providers login page.

When we initiate the login with Cognito and see it setting a 'csrf-state' cookie with a timeout of 5 minutes, so we assume this is the culprit, but could be a red herring. If we take longer than 5 minutes on the external login screen we are redirected to Cognito's hosted UI with an error of "Something went wrong", which isn't the user experience we are looking for.

[image: Error page on Hosted UI]

We are looking to increase the duration and/or stop it showing the hosted UI. Ideally we would have it redirect to a page within our application where we will give a descriptive error and the option to re-initiate the process.

I can't see anything in the management console set to 5 minutes, but have tried changing the "Authentication flow session duration", who's name seems to suggest it is exactly what I am after (but which was set to 3 minutes anyway, so it can't be), to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

We've found a way to do this using AWS WAF's support for Cognito.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/08/amazon-cognito-enables-native-support-aws-waf/

What you actually have to do is create a Web ACL in WAF with your Cognito pool as the associated resource, then set up a rule that blocks all access to the Cognito hosted UI pages and instead redirects the user to your app.

You can define the rule with JSON, so here's the JSON I had from my initial test the other day. It uses the `302` status and `Location` header to tell the client to redirect away.

```
{
  "Name": "disallow_cognito_hosted_ui_login_endpoint",
  "Priority": 0,
  "Statement": {
    "ByteMatchStatement": {
      "SearchString": "/login",
      "FieldToMatch": {
        "UriPath": {}
      },
      "TextTransformations": [
        {
          "Priority": 0,
          "Type": "NONE"
        }
      ],
      "PositionalConstraint": "STARTS_WITH"
    }
  },
  "Action": {
    "Block": {
      "CustomResponse": {
        "ResponseCode": 302,
        "CustomResponseBodyKey": "cognito-waf-auth-page-redirect",
        "ResponseHeaders": [
          {
            "Name": "Location",
            "Value": "https://login.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "disallow_cognito_hosted_ui_login_endpoint"
  }
}
```

Obviously, change the redirect URL to whatever you want it to be, we just send them back to our login page.

You also need to define a custom response body and refer to it by its key (the key is referenced in that JSON, but the definition of the custom response body isn't there). I found that just the `Location` header wasn't enough to redirect, I had to define a custom response body too (though it redirects before actually showing it).

You should be able to get this 1 rule to redirect away from all the hosted UI pages ( which are listed here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/hosted-UI-endpoints.html ) by changing the URI matching to a regex that matches all the pages. Careful it doesn't match any hosted UI enpdoints that you do want to keep working (e.g. we use the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint for our SSO journey).

Hope that helps!